# Why my code doesn't save/load my data in python?

Tags: python, database, file, storage, pickle

I use the following code(you can copy and run the code, it works) to load(if exists) and save the data to reuse it in the next execution of my program, but it doesn't work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import requests
import pickle

z = []


try:
    with open('3_tir.pickle', 'rb') as f:    
           last_prices = pickle.load(f)
           print("pickle loaded")
   #f = open("last_prices.txt", 'a+')
   #f.read()


except Exception:
    #f = open("last_prices.txt", 'a+')
    pass

for i in range(25200):

    time.sleep(1)

    with requests.Session() as s:
           data = {'current' : 'none' }            
           r = s.get('http://call5.tgju.org/ajax.json?2019061716-20190617171520-I4OJ3OcWf4gtpzr3JNC5' , json = data ).json()

    plt.clf()
    price = r['current']['diff_aud_usd']['p']
    z.append(price)
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot(z)
    plt.pause(0.1)
    with open('3_tir.pickle', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(last_prices, f)

    #   f.write(last_prices)
    #   f.close()
```

I tried to use both pickle and file way but none of them worked! I get no errors but data won't be saved and program plots only the new data.

Comment: Maybe an exception was raised? Using `except Exception` is generally a bad idea, as it will hide whatever happens. Use only specific exceptions. In your case, try to see what happens without this `try...except` block.

Comment: First, I'd check if the `3_tir.pickle` file is actually present on your filesystem. Then, I'd review the code as you don't seem to use `last_prices` from your backup file, as you always update it from `s.post` answer.

Comment: Also, you redefine `last_prices` in your code, but never update or use the values you supposedly loaded at the beginning.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille: I think the problem is that I can not add new values to the `pickle` and it makes it again each time! But I don't know how should I append new data to in instead of recreation?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille: I completed the code that you can copy and run it to see the result.